# Database design - Follow System of billions of records

Tags: mysql, mongodb, performance, database

I am working on a social android application that have the same followers system like **soundcloud**. 

I know that it can be implemented easily like this in **MySQL**, a follow table that hold both the follower and the one he followed

```
follower_id   following_id
1             2
4             1
6             2
9             6
.             .
.             .
.             .
```

and use both ids as a primary key.

**But the problem is** We are expecting the network to grow to millions of users.

Imagine only 1 million users that for average everyone would have 500 followers and following 500 persons.

That will result in a table of about **1,000 * 1,000,000 = 1,000,000,000 records** and that will continue to grow!

Could **MySQL** perform well in such circumstances? 
I could use **MongoDB** and store it like this

```
user_id     followers                                   following
1           [embedded documents holding followers]       [embedded documents holding following]
2           [embedded documents holding followers]       [embedded documents holding following]
3           [embedded documents holding followers]       [embedded documents holding following]
...
```

**The problem here** is not the performance - as i think - but will be that ***mongo doesn't support Transactions*** because for every following action I should store it in 2 documents!

So, what do you think is the best approach to do this? Could MySQL perform well if table grow to be billions of rows?!! Is there any other efficient design?!

Comment: You ask if MySQL would perform well in such circumstances. At the point at which your MySQL model struggles to cope with your data set either you will be rich enough to easily fix any such problems with professional assistance, or too rich to care.

Comment: Why do people think that if you stick different software onto hardware, that it performs different? This is not how our Universe, or IT for that matter, works. If you have bad hardware, slow disks, terrible network - no amount of software can fix that. If you have fast hardware, fast disks, sufficient RAM - then yes, any software will fly. Billions of records isn't much for computers. You're worried about the wrong thing here, what you should consider is allocating adequate hardware for this instead of min-maxing with data model or thinking of MongoDB. MongoDB doesn't do magic stuff.

Comment: Billions of rows is not a lot (especially if they are tuples of 2 4byte ints).

Comment: For each user document, just have 'followers' and 'following' be arrays of the _ids of the other users. Use MongooseJS populate when you want to grab it all in one shot.

Comment: The table (in MySQL) is rather simple.  But what will you do with the data?  What `SELECTs`?  Do you need to remove a 'follow'?  Are users 'grouped' in any way?

Comment: @RickJames The queries used
SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE follower_id = ...
SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE following_id = ...

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Follow (
    er_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL  COMMENT 'follower',
    ee_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL  COMMENT 'followee',
    PRIMARY KEY(er_id, ee_id),
    INDEX(ee_id, er_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

That way, you can get from er to ee *and* vice versa.

With that MySQL table structure and a billion rows and 500 followers, `SELECT er_id FROM tbl WHERE ee_id = 1234;` (and vice versa) will usually take only 10-20 milliseconds, even on spinning drives.

(The sameness of `follower_id` and `followee_id` led me to shorten the column names.)